# How to display the form control value in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I am trying to display the form control in the span tag not in input tag. So I have tried the below one

```
<div formArrayName="genes">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let gene of genesControls.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
                <span>
                {{gene.position}} //not working
                {{position}} //not working
                {{gene.position.value}} //not working
                {{position.value}} //not working
                </span>

                <!--input formControlName="position" id="pos"> This is working-->
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I am trying inside the input tag it is working but with the span or some other tag it is not working, I don't know what is going here, As per document I tried with values also but something went wrong. How can I fix this one?

Comment: Could you show the data inside genesControl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to access their values, you can access it through:

```
     <tbody *ngFor="let gene of genesControls.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
            <span>{{gene.value.position}}</span>

            <!--input formControlName="position" id="pos"> This is working-->
        </td>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between `gene.controls.position.value` and `gene.value.position`?

Comment: Since you are already accessing the data within a FormGroup you can access its properties by calling its value first. If you had consoled it before, if we have form = new FormGroup({name: 'test', age: 7}) and you perform console.log(form.value), it will give you {name: 'test', age: 7} so if you want to fetch the name property then you can perform console.log(form.value.name) so in your case under FormArray there are an array of FormGroups so we can access their values of each FormGroup through form.value or in your case gene.value so we specifiy what property to show, so gene.value.position

Answer (score 4):

As I see from your code, `gene` in itself is a compound control. So, to access the value of each inner controls, you would need to get value as e.g. `gene.controls.position.value`.

So, the code would look like following:

```html
<div formArrayName="genes">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let gene of genesControls.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
                <span>{{gene.controls.position.value}}</span>

                <!--input formControlName="position" id="pos"> This is working-->
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The other option would be to use `gene.value.position`

=== **Some Background** ===

In this scenario there is no actual difference in the behaviour. The way it works, though is different. So, each form (`FormGroup` or `FormArray`) as well as each `FormControl` extends the `AbstractControl` class which has a `value` property.

Elements of types `FormGroup` and `FormArray` also have a property `controls`, representing a group of all inner controls.

For `FormGroup` it looks like this: `[key: string]: AbstractControl`

For `FormArray` it looks like this: `AbstractControl[]`

When you access the `value` property of a deeply-nested form (`form.value`), it gives you the `value` of everything combined in a single object.

As Angular doc describes it `value` is:

> The current value of the control.
>   For a FormControl, the current value.
>   For a FormGroup, the values of enabled controls as an object with a key-value pair for each member of the group.
>   For a FormArray, the values of enabled controls as an array.

If you have a deeply nested form, you know that you can access the whole form value by `form.value`. This will be a simple js object.

For compound controls that are basically `FormGroup`s, you can access `controls` property and then get a value of a single control.

Comment: Could you explain **how** you can see from his code that `gene` is a compound control?